# AngularJS : change directive scope from transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

How can I change directive variable (which is in directive controller) from another controller which is in transclude ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change variable across the controllers then you have to use $rootScope instead of $scope. For example:

abc is your variable.

use it like this:

```
$rootScope.abc = 1; (directive controller)

// and change it's value in other controller

$rootScope.abc = 2; (another controller)
```

Comment: This works, but if I have some instances of directive ? I need to change variable only for that directive instance :)